# How can I conditionally include a framework in XCode?

Tags: ios5, xcode4, frameworks, ios6

I have an app I've been building in XCode 4.4 targeting iOS 5. Now that the XCode 4.5 beta is out I wanted to try my app, utilizing one of it's new frameworks.

However when I get back into XCode 4.4 it complains it cannot find the newer framework I've included, because it does not exist in iOS 5.

How can I develop my app with the future iOS 6 in mind, telling XCode to ignore the newer frameworks when I'm in the older XCode?

p.s. Thanks for putting up with what I feel is a very amateur question :)

Comment: I'm not 100% about this but I don't think Apple will even approve apps including iOS 6 code until it is formally released.

Comment: I think your right. Apps still need to be built with Xcode 4.3 for submitting to the app store. I'm just confused about how devs manage coding in both the current version of Xcode and the new beta. I want to avoid creating a fork of the codebase if its possible.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you are asking for answer. Think you are in need of a solution like in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6033512/1424174). i.e. You can set `optional` value to the framework which is not available in different versions.