# How to make sure my reusable static library doesn't force my project to include multiple frameworks?

Tags: objective-c

I try to put some reusable functions into my own static library but i noticed one problem.

Let's say the static library has many functions and some requires quartz core framework, some requires messgeUI etc.

When I build a new project, I include this static library project into my code so that I can reuse those functions.

Now even if I only use a simple function that doesn't require any frameworks, I am forced to include all the quartzcore, message UI frameworks or I will face build errors because the static library requires them- but I do not need all of them!

How can I design a better general purpose static library that doesn't force people to include frameworks that is not used by them at all?

Comment: why did i get a downvote for this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use weak linking - if weak linkage is used, unused symbols (functions, methods, global variables) don't have to be present at linking time.

Comment: hi, maybe my question is not clear, but weak linking doesnt really help in my situation. i found a question who has the same problem as me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009175/static-library-using-frameworks-in-specific-projects

Comment: @dunforget In this case: it's either 1. not possible or 2. you have to use the `dlopen()` API (but `dlsym()`ing each and every function is really cumbersome and bad practice).

Comment: hi, can you briefly advise me what's the correct way to have a bunch of reusable codes being shared by multiple projects? i thought having a custom static library is the way to go...

Comment: @dunforget Yes, a custom static library is good. And you will have to link to whatever libraries it uses.